# How do i get an ordered basis consisting of eigenvectors in this problem?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a linear operator on $\mathbb{R}_2[X]$ such that $T(f(X))=Xf'(X) + f(2)X + f(3)$.

*How do i evaluate a basis consisting of eigenvectors of $T$?*

Below is what i have tried:

Let $s$ be the standard ordered basis for $\mathbb{R}_2[X]$, that is, $\{1,X,X^2\}$.

Then,$\det(XI - [T]_s)=X(X-2)(X-4)$ hence $0,2,4$ are unique eigenvalues of $T$.

Since **"nonzero vector $v$ is an eigenvector of $[T]_s$ corresponding to 2 iff $v\in \ker(2I - [T]_s)$"** and $\ker(2I-[T]_s)=span((1,3,0))$, $X+3$ is a eigenvector of $T$ corresponding to $2$. (Here, (1,3,0) is a 3-tuple)

However, you can see that $4X^2 - 13X - 3$ is an eigenvector of $T$ corresponding to $2$. How can this be possible and how can i derive this polynomial is an eigenvector correspoding to $2$?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I don't understand why did you remove "fakeproof" tag. I think something must be wrong in my argument since the sentence i emphasized above is a theorem..

Comment: fake-proof is for proving obvious fallacies like $2=1$ proofs

Answer (score 1):

matrix of T at $\{1,x,x^2\}$ is

[1,3,9;1,3,4;0,0,2] and so correspond $\lambda =2$ will be asnwers of system :
$([1,3,9;1,3,4;0,0,2]-2I_{3*3})[x,y]_{column}=0$
exactly solutions of 
$x_3$can accept ar bitaray value
and so :

$-x_1+3x_2=-9x_3

x_1-2x_2=-4x_3$

if put $x_3=4$ you will see that (-3,-13,4) is an answer of this system